# Can someone help me identify this Japanese font?

Tags: fonts, font-identification, japanese

[image]

I've searched on google and font sites. The closest I found was *[ Soukou Mincho ]*, but it's not quite the same. Help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Traced back the page I screenshotted image from: https://realkana.com/hiragana/ (Bottom box, second font)

---

U̶P̶D̶A̶T̶E̶:̶ ̶A̶f̶t̶e̶r̶ ̶b̶r̶o̶w̶s̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶J̶a̶p̶a̶n̶e̶s̶e̶ ̶I̶ ̶f̶i̶n̶a̶l̶l̶y̶ ̶f̶o̶u̶n̶d̶ ̶i̶t̶.̶ ̶T̶h̶a̶n̶k̶s̶ ̶e̶v̶e̶r̶y̶o̶n̶e̶.̶ ̶F̶o̶n̶t̶: もじくみ仮名

♦ WELP. At a closer inspection, they're different. [paste wrysmile.jpg here]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to **GDSE**; please look around [tour] to get a sense of who we are as a community, and what we're about. Look at [ask] and [answer] questions, to learn how to frame acceptable queries and what to expect of replies and answers; please also look at [help/behavior] to understand our community's internal behavioural expectations. You should also look at this canonic question: https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/what-are-the-requirements-for-font-identification-questions

Comment: Hi GerardFalla. Did you really have to point that out? I have specified my search on google, multiple font sites and my unsatisfactory finding. IMG is from a while back, I doubt that would mean anything.

I followed the template of similar questions nobody had a problem with. Even under the expectation of no reply, that led me to sign up and ask ..only to get slammed by you who seem to be insinuating I've made a grave mistake.

OH. For tagging "font" while talking about font? Haha wow. If these unique rules were so important it should've been introduced upon registration.

Comment: Again, welcome... a comment encouraging question refinement (which in fact is not what you received) and/or providing an informational referent to a canonical font ID question is in no way a ‘slam’, either in intent or in execution. Had I an issue with how you’d worded, I’d have said so unequivocally - if I felt this question strayed far enough from the “how to ask font questions” guidelines, I’d have voted to close, which I didn’t do: I encourage you to read for comprehension, not umbrage. I’m hoping someone in our group of font stalwarts can help you find this font!

Comment: Could you mention where you got this kana listing? It might give some hints while also properly crediting the image source.

Comment: The image is a screenshot I took and edited myself from some time ago. Unfortunately I don't remember the site itself but I could try tracing it back. Give me a day or two.

Comment: https://realkana.com/hiragana/ (Bottom box, second font)

Comment: I am on a tablet right now. If you are on a PC, right-click in your browser on that font symbol and pick "inspect element". Typically you will learn lots about that webpage and might find references to Google fonts or a similar service. Later more.

Comment: Hmm I actually tried that already. The japanese texts are within <div> / jquery, not highlightable. This is all I get: 'lucida grande',verdana,sans-serif; https://realkana.com/img/k/50/kana@2x.png

Comment: UPDATE: After browsing in japanese I finally found it. Thanks everyone. Font: もじくみ仮名

Comment: ** Welp. At a closer inspection, they're different. Never mind my false discovery.

Comment: I found two similar fonts: [GL Antique Plus](https://www.freejapanesefont.com/gl-antique-plus/) and [Yu Mincho](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/jiyu-kobo/yu-mincho-36p-kana/)

Answer (score 2):

It's [光朝](https://www.morisawa.co.jp/fonts/specimen/1442) released by Morisawa. You can use it partially freely in the form of web font via their [TypeSquare](https://typesquare.com/) service.

[image]

I'm very sure that it is an adaptation of [築地初号仮名](https://www.screen.co.jp/ga_product/sento/pro/typography/05typo/05_1typo.html), a classic old-style typeface in Japanese metal type history. It has a lot of modern revivals (so is your もじくみ仮名) as much as Caslon and Garamond do, so you can easily find similar fonts.

- [築地体初号仮名](https://www.morisawa.co.jp/fonts/specimen/1861)
- [かな民友明朝](https://l-l-l.jp/wp/?p=1785) (not available for DTP)
- [GL-築地初号](http://cute-freefont.flop.jp/tsyukiji-shogo.html) (free)
- [解築初号かな](https://font-kai.jp/kai-kanaa.html)